# Cannot recover signer

Tags: solidity, hardhat, typescript

I am facing a problem where recoveredAddress is not restored correctly. We assume that the address of the owner who originally deployed the smart contract is returned. Am I making some big mistake? Can someone please let me know? Thank you.

- "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0"
- "hardhat": "^2.17.3",

**contracts/VerifyToken.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract VerifyToken {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;

    address public signer;

    constructor() {
        signer = msg.sender;
    }

    function verify(bytes memory signature) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender));
        bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = messageHash.toEthSignedMessageHash();
        address recoveredSigner = ethSignedMessageHash.recover(signature);

        console.log("signer: %s", signer);
        console.log("recoveredSigner: %s", recoveredSigner);

        bool isValid = recoveredSigner == signer;

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

**/test/VerifyToken.ts**

```
import { loadFixture } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox/network-helpers";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("VerifyToken", function () {
  async function deployVerifyTokenFixture() {
    const [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const verifyToken = await ethers.deployContract("VerifyToken");
    await verifyToken.waitForDeployment();
    return { verifyToken, owner, addr1 };
  }

  describe("Verifying", function () {
    it("Should 1", async function () {
      const { verifyToken, owner } = await loadFixture(
        deployVerifyTokenFixture
      );

      const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(
        new ethers.AbiCoder().encode(["address"], [owner.address])
      );
      const signature = await owner.signMessage(ethers.toBeArray(messageHash));

      const isValid = await verifyToken.verify(signature);
      expect(isValid).to.equal(true);
    });

    it("Should 2", async function () {
      const { verifyToken, addr1 } = await loadFixture(
        deployVerifyTokenFixture
      );

      const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(
        new ethers.AbiCoder().encode(["address"], [addr1.address])
      );
      const signature = await addr1.signMessage(ethers.toBeArray(messageHash));

      const isValid = await verifyToken.verify(signature);
      expect(isValid).to.equal(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Most likely some minor error somewhere in code. Difficult to track down.

Comment: I'm sorry. There was a mistake in the code and it has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abiCoder.encode is *not* packed, eg.:

```js
abiCoder.encode(["address"], ['0x473173aDa23BE87a4740646b09F9c22d115CE5a0'])
'0x000000000000000000000000473173ada23be87a4740646b09f9c22d115ce5a0'
```

but in solidity you used `abi.encodePacked` instead of `abi.encode`:

```js
abi.encodePacked(address(0x473173aDa23BE87a4740646b09F9c22d115CE5a0))
hex"473173ada23be87a4740646b09f9c22d115ce5a0"
```

Comment: Oh! That was very helpful. Thank you very much! I confirmed that it works fine with abi.encode.